# How do I delete products in magmi

Tags: products, magmi, delete

I have been using magmi to import products in bulk, but now need to delete some of them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a column to your import with this as the header name: **magmi:delete**

1 is to delete the product
0 is to not delete the product

You want to use the Product Deleter v0.0.2 plugin.

Comment: In my case Magmi tries to Clean flat tables before reindexing. I'm not sure if that causes this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction. There is some timelimit with the hosting package so I guess it is related to that. Is there a way to make it work? Already tried to laynt the delete process with magmi.cli.php in shell but with no luck as it seems to fail the delete task too as products are not deleted.

Comment: Hi, what about product resources like "media files" - Are they also deleted from DB and/or filesystem ? Do you have any experiences about this topic ? Regards

Answer (score 6):

First you need to enable the Product Deleter Plugin.

[image]
Then you need to create a CSV, with columns "sku" and "magmi:delete". For example:

```
"sku","magmi:delete"
"00001","1"
"00004","1"
```

Then run your import.

Answer (score 0):

**Click Here to add MAGMI into your module** -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351175

**Enable Product Deleter plugin.**

[image]

> **Using CSV**

```
"sku","magmi:delete"
"sku1","1"
"sku2","1"
```

> **Using Code**

```
    $importData = [];
    $configProduct = new \Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump('productimport');
    $importData['sku'] = "your Product SKU";
    $importData['magmi:delete'] = "1";
    $configProduct->beginImportSession("default", "update");
    $run = $configProduct->ingest($importData);
    $configProduct->endImportSession();
```

> Check **catalog_eav_attribute** table in your db . If **is_configurable** column not present then update below code from **getConfigurableOptsFromAsId()** function in this file **.../magmi/plugins/base/itemprocessors/configurables/magmi_configurableprocessor.php**

```
    //$sql .= " JOIN $cea as cea ON cea.attribute_id=ea.attribute_id AND cea.is_global=1 AND cea.is_configurable=1";
    $sql .= " JOIN $cea as cea ON cea.attribute_id=ea.attribute_id AND cea.is_global=1";
} else {
    //$cond .= " AND ea.is_global=1 AND ea.is_configurable=1";
    $cond .= " AND ea.is_global=1";
```

***Note:- magmi:delete :  1 is to delete the product 0 is to not delete the product***