# How do I install the MagMi for Magento 2 extension?

Tags: magento2, magmi

I have downloaded and extracted the MagMi M2 module from https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2 but I have no idea how to install it.

I tried copying it into the `vendor` dir in several locations, ran `./magento setup`, but the module is nowhere to be found in my Magento 2 installation.

So, how do I install that module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not install for **magmi** just Copy **magmi**  in main folder

**/magmi**

and just the following your url you will be able to access the magmi

**http://installmagentourl/magmi/web/magmi.php**
and use default user: **magmi** paswd: **magmi**

You are good to go..

One thing more

go to 
**magmi/inc/magmi_engine.php** replace the one **511** line and replace else code and add you credential

```
else {
                $host = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "host", "localhost");
                $dbname = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "dbname", "magento");
                $user = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "user",'root');
                $pass = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "password",'root');
                $port = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "port", "3306");
            }
```

Comment: I get a login (basic http auth) screen, no user/pass combo to be found. I am logged in into my Magento 2 admin backend.

Comment: @BartFriederichs use default login for`user: magmi paswd: magmi`

Comment: OK, I can login now, but it gives me just PHP errors (engine not given). I fixed one and I get a lot more now (permission denied, sql connection fail). This really doesn't look like the way to use this.

Comment: @BartFriederichs i posted the solution regarding the error that i faced with magmi hope it will help you too.

Comment: I you have the database settings correct, you can use the Magento user/password combo.

Comment: @BartFriederichs after the setting you can only login from Magento user/password combo.

Comment: Also, the webserver needs write access to plugins, conf and state.

Comment: Hi @QaisarSatti i have download magmi and placed in magento 2 root folder and provided magento 2 database details changed in magmi_engine.php but i unable to access in the fronted as u said  http://magento2/magmi/web/magmi.php  ?? showing forbidden ? please advise

Comment: @NagarajuKasa give permission to folder.

Comment: Thanks @QaisarSatti now its working but bottom of the page getting error like https://prnt.sc/lxd3hd can u please advise let me know is this magmi compatible for magento2.2.X (or) magento 2.3 etc CE?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa add db credential that are mention in answer.

Comment: @QaisarSatti yes i have used same but no luck https://prnt.sc/lxddhe

Comment: @Nagaraju Kasa 
$user = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "user", "root");
$pass = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "password", "kspl1234");
when change you can f5 and use user and pass of admin backend to authen

Comment: @NagarajuK May i know which folder you paste the magmi folder?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of setting MAGMI is to create the following file:

**magmi/conf/magmi.ini**

just copy/rename the **magmi/conf/magmi.ini.default** file where you can get the basic settings

Then open http://installmagentourl/magmi/web/magmi.php and use your **Magento admin account** to authenticate and start setting profiles and importing products etc.

Comment: Warning: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/test/pub/magmi/inc/magmi_auth.php on line 69

Warning: substr() expects parameter 3 to be int, string given in /var/www/html/test/pub/magmi/inc/magmi_auth.php on line 69

Warning: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/test/pub/magmi/inc/magmi_auth.php on line 71  Any help thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you do this settings:

```
else {
                $host = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "host", "localhost");
                $dbname = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "dbname", "magento");
                $user = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "user",'root');
                $pass = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "password",'root');
                $port = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "port", "3306");
            }
```

then in first prompt you have to give your admin username/password instead of magmi/magmi

Answer (score 1):

-> **Download Magmi Module (Place magmi folder At  magetnoRoot or magetnoRoot/pub path of your Magento)**

```
https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2
```

-> **Go to path in URL**

```
http://www.HostName.com/magmi/web/magmi.php

UserName: magmi
Password: magmi
```

> Upon installing Magmi and visiting the web panel for the first time, the default username and password are both set to "magmi". Once successfully logged in, configure Magmi with the Magento database credentials (under Configure Global Parameters) and then save the settings. Afterwards, one can simply use their Magento administrative (backend) credentials to login to Magmi.

-> **create file at /var/www/html/magentoRoot/magmi/conf/magmi.ini** if magmi at magentoRoot

OR

-> **create file at /var/www/html/magentoRoot/pub/magmi/conf/magmi.ini** if magmi at magentoRoot/pub

**magmi.ini**

```
[DATABASE]
dbname="magento database name"
host="magento database host"
port = "3306"
user=database user
resource = "default_setup"
unix_socket =
password="database password"
table_prefix=
[MAGENTO]
basedir="/var/www/html/magentoRoot"
[GLOBAL]
;---- Uncomment the following line to have a custom import report step, defaults to 100
step = "1"
multiselect_sep = ","
dirmask = "755"
filemask = "644"
```

> **Add into your module registration.php file**

-> If Your magmi folder on magentoRoot/pub then

**registration.php**

```
<?php
require_once BP . "/pub/magmi/plugins/inc/magmi_datasource.php";
require_once BP . "/pub/magmi/integration/inc/productimport_datapump.php";

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

-> If your magmi folder On Magento Root Then

**registration.php**

```
<?php
require_once BP . "/magmi/plugins/inc/magmi_datasource.php";
require_once BP . "/magmi/integration/inc/productimport_datapump.php";

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Try This Code For Import Product

```
$productImport = new \Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump('productimport');
$item = "product field array";
$productImport->beginImportSession("default", "create");// Mode: xcreate, create, update
$run = $productImport->ingest($item);
$productImport->endImportSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add database name, database username and password, as well as set the permission for the database user to use that database

Comment: Hi I am working on Magento 2.2.2 and have the same issue I have tried the suggestion in this post and the link but still issue is there please can anyone offer any help i need this to update store asap

Comment: password and login is correct and working - checked please can anyone post here 2 files
magmi/conf magmi.ini

and

magmi/inc magmi_engine.php

So I can compare sytax when entering the password and database details

Please change the actual pass and details before posting.