# Fatal Error with Magmi for Magento2

Tags: magento2, magmi

I'm trying Magmi for Magento2.2 but i get this error, the database user and pw is correct, anyone knows what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try to login with **magento admin password** instead of default magmi password. I also had this issue when I was installed for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

go to **magmi/inc/magmi_engine.php** replace the one **511** line and replace else code and add your database credential.

replace code

```
else {
                $host = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "host", "localhost");
                $dbname = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "dbname", "magento");
                $user = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "user");
                $pass = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "password");
                $port = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "port", "3306");
            }
```

with

```
else {
                $host = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "host", "localhost");
                $dbname = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "dbname", "magento");
                $user = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "user",'root');
                $pass = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "password",'root');
                $port = $this->getProp("DATABASE", "port", "3306");
            }
```

already answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208225/how-do-i-install-the-magmi-for-magento-2-extension/208229#208229) but here is about specific problem

Comment: Hi I am working on Magento 2.2.2 and have the same issue I have tried the suggestion in this post and the link but still issue is there please can anyone offer any help i need this to update store asap