# Magento 2: Error 500 with correct Password in Magmi.ini

Tags: magento2, php-7, magmi

My issue is very closely related to Magmi for magento2 and this question here **[Fatal Error with Magmi for Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208371/fatal-error-with-magmi-for-magento2)**.

I've noticed when I enter my database credentials correctly in the **magmi_engine.php** file that the password I enter is stripped of capital letters.

If I manually amend in the magmi.ini file I get a 500 server error. Remove the capitals and the magmi page displays again. It is a requirement to have Capitals in the MySQL user password though so not sure how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Make php error reporting on magmi

add below code to file magmi/web/magmi.php to ON error reporting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Make sure if you have php version <7.2 then user below git repository for magmi download https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/tree/82ae373630c5291fc72ce948935916a811dc4f8b

Latest version URL for Magento 2 : https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2 
 (for PHP 7.2 )

Answer (score 0):

thanks this is the error message

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...inc/magmi_auth.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in .../inc/magmi_auth.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ../inc/magmi_auth.php on line 47

Notice: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES' in ../inc/magmi_auth.php on line 63

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: random_bytes() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given in ../inc/magmi_auth.php:63 Stack tra

Comment: By default 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES' not installed on php version <7.2 Please Download git repository  https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/tree/82ae373630c5291fc72ce948935916a811dc4f8b 
I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES' not installed on php version <7.2 Please Download git repository  https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/tree/82ae373630c5291fc72ce948935916a811dc4f8b 
I have fixed the issue.