# Magento 2: Error 500 with correct Password in Magmi.ini with PHP7.2

Tags: magento2, magmi, php-7.2

My question relates strongly to [Magento 2: Error 500 with correct Password in Magmi.ini](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287827/magento-2-error-500-with-correct-password-in-magmi-ini)

However I am not running PHP 7.1 but running PHP7.2.27 on centos 6 but still getting the sodium crypto error when using current version from github here https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2

when I try to use the version for php7.1 i get error returned

Performing Datasource Lookup...

Warning: fopen(/var/import/import.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /inc/magmi_csvreader.php on line 51

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /inc/magmi_mixin.php on line 28

Answer (score 0):

The version for PHP7.1 works with php 7.2 for centos 6 my error was another issue to do with the format of csv file