# Magento 2.2.5 - Delete all products and products images

Tags: magento2, catalog, products, csv, delete

I have a site with Magento 2.2.5, with thousands of products imported via Magmi v0.7.23-git with csv.

I tried to delete all these products with the Magmi utility 'Clear Catalog v1.0.4', and then reload the new products with a new csv.

The problem is that the new loaded products do not have the right images, some products have 2, 3 images that have nothing to do with it.

I also tried deleting all the records in these tables:
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`

But the problem remains.

**Which method do you recommend to delete all the products and images of these products from Magento correctly to ensure that no data of these products remains?**

Thank you all.

Comment: have to tried deleting from the BO?

Answer (score 0):

**Click Here to add MAGMI into your module** -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351175

**Enable Product Deleter plugin.**

[image]

> **Using CSV**

```
"sku","magmi:delete"
"sku1","1"
"sku2","1"
```

> **Using Code**

```
    $importData = [];
    $configProduct = new \Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump('productimport');
    $importData['sku'] = "your Product SKU";
    $importData['magmi:delete'] = "1";
    $configProduct->beginImportSession("default", "update");
    $run = $configProduct->ingest($importData);
    $configProduct->endImportSession();
```

> Check **catalog_eav_attribute** table in your db . If **is_configurable** column not present then update below code from **getConfigurableOptsFromAsId()** function in this file **.../magmi/plugins/base/itemprocessors/configurables/magmi_configurableprocessor.php**

```
    //$sql .= " JOIN $cea as cea ON cea.attribute_id=ea.attribute_id AND cea.is_global=1 AND cea.is_configurable=1";
    $sql .= " JOIN $cea as cea ON cea.attribute_id=ea.attribute_id AND cea.is_global=1";
} else {
    //$cond .= " AND ea.is_global=1 AND ea.is_configurable=1";
    $cond .= " AND ea.is_global=1";
```

***Note:- magmi:delete :  1 is to delete the product 0 is to not delete the product***